# Is there a way to trigger MFA programmatically for an in-app functionality to be run?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-msal, multi-factor-authentication, msal

I have a .NET application using Azure AD and I'm trying to implement a functionality which will require the user to redo the MFA authentication to be able to run an action. Is there any way to do this in .NET?

There's nothing on this in the Microsoft documentation but I've tried the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RequireMFA()
{
    return Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Authenticate" },
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

This doesn't do anything, just redirects but doesn't require the user to re-authenticate with MFA.